# Soft keyboard hides my Modal Bottom sheet edit text

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having a problem while dealing with bottomsheet ,actually soft keyboard hides my bottomsheet element .Can anyone help me

Comment: can you post some more details?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this style:

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="NotFloatingBottomDialog">
     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
     <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
     <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
     <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
</style>
```

And when you create the BottomSheetDialog use it:

```
val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(context, R.style.CustomBottomSheet)
```